# Proper HTTP response for unsupported page format (e.g. xml)?

Tags: rest, request, httpresponse

### Situation

I'm trying to create a REST API, where users can request responses in different formats.

For example, user can access:

> example.com/oranges/1.xml (returns results in XML)
>
> example.com/oranges/1.json (returns results in JSON)

### Question

**What's the proper HTTP response to indicate that a specific response format is not available?**

For example, user tries to access:

> example.com/oranges/1.yml (unsupported format)

**Do I throw a 404 or is there a better response?**

Comment: How about client error **HTTP 400 Bad Request**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're encoding the desired format in the URL, then 404 is indeed the correct response -- it tells the client that it will never, barring server changes, be able to do anything with that URL.

With proper HTTP content negotiation, using the `Accept` request-header (which would be the more RESTamentalist choice), the appropriate response for an unsupported type would be 406.

Comment: Good answer.  Admittedly, naughtily I implemented my api to use the 406 code whether it's specified in the URL, get params, or in the Accept header--even though its Restfully wrong and 404 should technically be used for the URL scenario. May I be forgiven by the REST overlords :P

Answer (score 0):

I'd use *400*. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: 415 is for when the client tries to POST (or PUT) data that have an unsupported type. That's a completely different situation.